# Exception handling - plsql

Tags: plsql

I have a problem. Am doing an insert function

```
case f1.RFD_CATEGORY_CODE when'O1' then 'C1GBC'
when 'O2' then 'C2GBC' else null end
```

the field is mandatory and thus instead of null i need to show an error message if the code is not taking C1GBC or C2GBC. and if the code is taking C1GBC or C2GBC then show successful as message.

i have create an exception below but am getting error

```
create or replace procedure CTP_CODE as
declare
--RFD_CAT_ERR varchar2;
RFD_CAT_ERR EXCEPTION;

begin
    if RFD_CATEGORY_CODE is '01' then RFD_CATEGORY_CODE is 'C1GBC';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No1. Successful Operation');
    else
        if RFD_CATEGORY_CODE is '02' then RFD_CATEGORY_CODE is 'C2GBC';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No2. Successful Operation');
        end if;
raise RFD_CAT_ERR;
end if;
EXCEPTION
when RFD_CAT_ERR then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error message!');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Code also wrong syntax..
Whenever your code goes in else condition it will throw error as after executing 2nd if it will go to "raise RFD_CAT_ERR;" part and raise an exception.
so u should handle error in elsif after 2nd If condition.

Comment: if RFD_CATEGORY_CODE = '01' then RFD_CATEGORY_CODE := 'C1GBC';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No1. Successful Operation');
    else
        if RFD_CATEGORY_CODE is '02' then RFD_CATEGORY_CODE is 'C2GBC';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No2. Successful Operation');
        else 
raise RFD_CAT_ERR;
end if;
end if;

Answer (score 1):

You say the field is mandatory. If by that you mean the field in the table is constrained as `not null` then you don't have to worry about raising an exception. The insert statement will do that for you. All you have to do is catch it in your exception handler and use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR to return a meaningful message.

Do that rather than try to print an error message. If your procedure is called by a batch process, there will be no one there to see it.

Comment: Yes, its the next step for my code. This is helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :D

```
   CASE f1.RFD_CATEGORY_CODE
      WHEN 'O1' THEN 'C1GBC'
      WHEN 'O2' THEN 'C2GBC'
   ELSE 'error'
```

Then raise any errors for exception